# indirect addressing problem about functions

Tags: c, arguments, parameter-passing, memory-address, strcat

strcat(s,t) copies the string t to the end of s,the following is initial code.

```
void strcat(char s[], char t[])
{
    int i, j;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (s[++i] != '\0');
    while ((s[i++] = t[j++]) != '\0');
}

#define MaxSize 100
int main()
{
    char str1[MaxSize] = { 'a','b','c','d' };
    char str2[MaxSize] = { 's','s' };
    strcat(str1, str2);
    printf("%s", str1);
    return 0;
}
```

1. system told me different levels of indirection between “strcat”:`“void (char *,char *)”`and`“char *(char *,const char *)”`. this is the first *why*?
2. after i change from `void strcat(char s[], char t[])`to `void* strcat(char s[], char t[])` there is no error. so it means i can only use pointer `void*` to <s>pass the address of **str1**</s> return type of **char***, but i can't use the parameter **s,t** of `strcat(char s[], char t[])` to modify the content of *str1*. if what i think is right,that will be the second *why*

Comment: `void` means the function *does not* return a value. `void*` means it returns a value of type `void*`.

Comment: You say with `void* strcat(char s[], char t[])` there is no error. There should be an error if the function does not return a value. You also say can only use pointer `void*` to pass the address of `str1`. No, `void*` is the return value, and you can use it to return any type of pointer.

Comment: `char *(char *,const char *)` is the signature of the standard lib's `strcat`. You are not supposed to write your own versions of these core functions. What happens if you name the fuction something else, e.g. `mystrcat`?

Comment: ... where "you are not supposed to" means "it violates the C language specification to".  Undefined behavior results from such violations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you guys very much, i should change the function name. e.g. **void strcat(char s[], char t[])** should be modified to **void mystrcat(char s[], char t[])**.
i want to use my own version of *strcat* but forgot it violated the C language specification. because i wrote code **# include< string.h>**.
after i realize this problem, **void strcat(char s[], char t[])** and ***void* strcat(char s[], char t[])** are both OK.